# saveInBackground throws NullPointerException when object is not null

Tags: android, parse-platform, nullpointerexception

I'm using Parse SDK for Android. And I faced the problem, when I'm trying to save ParseObject it throws a null pointer exception, but this object is not null. And before that, it was working just fine. I was changing and adding other things, but I didn't touch this one, and now it fails.
I have the Lighter class that extends ParseObject. And I'm trying to save it in the background:

```
lighterObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            message.setContent(enteredMessage);
                            message.setLocation(lighterObject.getParseGeoPoint("location"));

                            message.setUser(ParseObject.createWithoutData(user.getClassName(), user.getObjectId()));
                            message.setIsScanMessage("YES");
                            message.setType(1d);
                            message.setPublicReadWriteAcl();
                            user.put("lastLighter", ParseObject.createWithoutData(lighterObject.getClassName(), lighterObject.getObjectId()));
                            user.saveInBackground();
                            message.setLighter(ParseObject.createWithoutData(lighterObject.getClassName(), lighterObject.getObjectId()));
                            message.saveInBackground();

                            AppDelegate.getSharedPreferences().edit().putString(AppDelegate.LIGHTER_ID, lighterObject.getObjectId()).commit();
                            AppDelegate.getSharedPreferences().edit().putString(AppDelegate.LIGHTER_COLOR, color.toLowerCase()).commit();

                            progressBar.dismiss();
                            fragmentHolder.onMapRedirect();
                        } else {
                            progressBar.dismiss();
                            fragmentHolder.onMapRedirect();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to register a lighter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I debugged the code, and I can tell you for sure, that lighterObject is not null. And during debug, program goes to else statement but the error says that I'm trying to use `getObjectId()` method on a null object. Here are the logs:

```
 W/System.err﹕ com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.parse.ParseUser.getObjectId()' on a null object reference
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:943)
 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
 W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.parse.ParseUser.getObjectId()' on a null object reference
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseUser.validateSave(ParseUser.java:582)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$40$2$3$1$1.then(ParseObject.java:2350)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$40$2$3$1$1.then(ParseObject.java:2342)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.access$200(Task.java:31)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$10.then(Task.java:592)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$10.then(Task.java:589)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:832)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.access$600(Task.java:31)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:887)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:921)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$3.then(ParseObject.java:401)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$3.then(ParseObject.java:398)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$13.run(Task.java:755)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:746)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:545)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:556)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject.enqueueForAll(ParseObject.java:398)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$40$2$3.then(ParseObject.java:2339)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$40$2$3.then(ParseObject.java:2328)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:702)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:690)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:574)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:690)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:680)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:714)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$40$2.then(ParseObject.java:2328)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$40$2.then(ParseObject.java:2279)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:702)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:690)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:574)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:690)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:680)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:503)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:495)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:574)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWhile(Task.java:509)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWhile(Task.java:465)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$40.then(ParseObject.java:2274)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$40.then(ParseObject.java:2263)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:702)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:690)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:574)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:690)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:680)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:714)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject.deepSaveAsync(ParseObject.java:2263)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject.access$400(ParseObject.java:52)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$13.then(ParseObject.java:1403)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$13.then(ParseObject.java:1393)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:702)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:690)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:574)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:690)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:680)
 W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.onSuccessTask(Task.java:714)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject.saveAsync(ParseObject.java:1371)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$10.then(ParseObject.java:1358)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject$10.then(ParseObject.java:1354)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.TaskQueue.enqueue(TaskQueue.java:61)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject.saveInBackground(ParseObject.java:1354)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject.saveInBackground(ParseObject.java:1442)
 W/System.err﹕ at ergotech.com.cricket.Fragments.FragmentLighterNewOwner$2.onClick(FragmentLighterNewOwner.java:139)
 W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4832)
 W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19839)
```

Comment: I think ur user object is null try to check user object before use it.

Comment: Here is my debug output:
![Screenshot of debug window](http://i.piccy.info/i9/4b228f026110287a1c18c9a5fb3e5218/1430401430/29775/895576/Debug_User.png)

Comment: If your `user` object isn't `null`, then it's not the cause of the NPE, obviously. However, on the same line, you're passing it into a method, and the return value of that method is passed into another method. Plenty of opportunity for NPE here. Change that part of your code so that it doesn't use nested method invocations, but only one method per line and assign the return value to a local variable. Then debug again, one of your objects will be `null`.

Comment: I believe your problem lies with the user object, but it doesn't necessary have to be null, for example, if you create a new user and request its objectId before saving it, it returns null, since the Parse Database will assign it an objectId when the object is saved. And I'm not sure but I also believe that after saving it you'd have to refetch the item to make sure it's up to date since a local object only reflects the state of the object when it was fetched from the database. Oh and the reason why I think it's the user and not lighterObject: **com.parse.ParseUser**.getObjectId();

Comment: After erasing the database, it doesn't throw NPE. It doesn't save lighterObject at all.

Comment: if possible try deleting the class in parse dashboard and let the android code create one automatically with the same code you have. I know it sounds crazy but give it a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you declaring lighterObject as final?

https://parse.com/questions/how-to-get-the-parse-object-id-after-saving-it-with-saveinbackgroud